# How to change default meta values in wordpress

Tags: term-meta

[image: When I share my website link to another it shows default template detail. I want to change these meta descriptions. How can I do that? Please help me.]

I am very thankful to you all.

Answer (score 0):

Click the "General" menu item.
Type your new description into the input box labeled "Tagline."
Click the "Save Changes" button to save your new Tagline.

Or

Install the plugin “WordPress SEO by Yoast” and edit the snippet for the home page.

Comment: Thanks, dear its changed but still, when I send a link to another the old content is still showing.

Comment: Thanks . Can you send the link?

Comment: missundergarments.com

Comment: All right !!
I tested this link a lot. Correctly displays the description :

At Miss Undergarments we offer maximum variety of styles, sizes and colors and proud to be the variety seller Destination in Pakistan. We provide .....